# Explanation for exact amounts ratio between up,down quarks and electrons in a universe

Tags: cosmology, electrons, big-bang, quarks, leptons

As I've understood in the quark era $\approx (10^{-12} - 10^{-6}) \,\text{s}$ unified interaction has decoupled into Leptons and Quarks. Given that now Hydrogen+Helium atoms accounts for $97.9\%$ of [matter composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Universe) in a universe, one can calculate from $^{1}_1\text{H}, \, ^{4}_2\text{He}$ - main isotopes composition, that for each electron in a universe there's corresponding $2.\overset{\frown }{6}\text{u}$ and $2.\overset{\frown }{3}\text{d}$ quarks. Here comes the question.
Why early universe decoupled matter in quark era exactly so that quarks remains in mentioned above proportion compared to electron amount if leptons and quarks were created **independently** of each other ? Is this just a "nice" anthropic coincidence adjusted so that, most abundant elements could be borned or simply it just happened for no reason and next BigBang could favor other proportions between electrons and quarks ?

Comment: Check your nucleon count. The ratio of up to down quarks is heavily skewed in favor of up, and both the $u:d$ ratio and the $e^-:d$ ratio have been shifting towards $d$ since the beginning of stellar fusion, since hydrogen fusion turns protons and electrons ($uud + e^-$) into neutrons ($udd$).

Also note that neither flavor nor electron count are independently conserved. Beta decay and electron capture conserve charge and color, but not flavor or number of electrons.

Comment: What's wrong with nucleon count ? It is $6u+6d$ quarks in total for $\text{H},\text{He}$ most abundant isotopes. I do not say anything about $u/e, d/e$ ratio dynamics, of course it could be a bit different in universe early times and now may choose yet different evolution path. Yet, basic question remains the same - of WHY there was such $u/e, d/e$ ratios as it was in the beginning of quark era and what caused it. Your comment does not answers this question at all.

Comment: $^1H$ has 2u and 1d, $^4He$ has 6u and 6d. with a 3:1 H:He ratio, that's 18:12 = 3:2 = u:d. As for my comment not being an answer... if I had a complete answer I would have given an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thanks, now I just realized that in total quark counts I was missing to add $\text{H}$ quarks.

Comment: Isn't your question simply: "Why does the universe have no net electric charge?"

Comment: Don't know maybe, if from universe zero net charge follows exact $u/e$, $d/e$ ratios - then yes. In that case still remains question, **can** universe be electrically charged in some BigBang iteration, i.e. can it be formed like so, or it can't, because it would be unstable then ?